# Is there a way to overwrite the release:prepare svn tag commit message?

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the maven release plugin to perform a release.  We recently added a requirement to our svn that all checkin message must contain pattern (e.g. XYZ-123).  When mvn release:prepare is trying to do the "tag", it will fail svn checkin because the default message for the commit is the the "[maven-scm] blah blah blah" format instead of the one our pre-commit check is looking for.  Is there a way to overwrite this message for svn checking for tagging with maven release plugin?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`scmCommentPrefix`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#scmCommentPrefix) parameter:

> The message prefix to use for all SCM changes.
>
> Default: `[maven-release-plugin]`

I believe this should work:

```
-DscmCommentPrefix=XYZ-123
```

Comment: The link is not pointing to the correct url. The parameter is on the goal release:prepare -  [scmCommentPrefix](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#scmCommentPrefix)